# Mysql order specific value on last, and other rest became first

Tags: mysql

So i have table let said is master_mkt
on table i have 1 field group_mkt

```
   group_mkt
--------------------
ADIDAS
AMERS TEAM
CONTINENT 8-HOLLIT
E-PRIMA
E-PRIME
IKEA
RETAIL
SMART MED
TNF/COLUMBIA/PVH
UNIQLO
```

On that list i wanna AMERS TEAM,E-PRIMA, & E-PRIME became on last order, and the rest is first, like these

```
  group_mkt
   --------------------
  ADIDAS
  CONTINENT 8-HOLLIT
  IKEA
  RETAIL
  SMART MED
  TNF/COLUMBIA/PVH
  UNIQLO
  AMERS TEAM
  E-PRIMA
  E-PRIME
```

How do i do that, and please don't said i need specific all value, cause i'm afraid there's gonna be new member group_mkt so i do not need re input specific order.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query (although, as it happens, I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specific values to appear at the end:

```
order by group_mkt="E-PRIME",group_mkt="E-PRIMA",group_mkt="AMERS TEAM",group_mkt
```

or

```
order by case group_mkt when "AMERS TEAM" then 1 when "E-PRIMA" then 2 when "E-PRIME" then 3 end,group_mkt
```

or

```
order by field(group_mkt, "AMERS TEAM", "E-PRIMA", "E_PRIME"), group_mkt
```

Or if you want a set of values to be sorted in order, but after any values not in your set:

```
order by group_mkt in ("AMERS TEAM", "E-PRIMA", "E_PRIME"), group_mkt
```

Comment: Or maybe `order by group_mkt IN ("E-PRIME", "E-PRIMA", "AMERS TEAM"), group_mkt` if the ordering in this "place last" group doesn't matter.

Comment: @Akina From the example, it looks like all the others are alphabetical.

Comment: @ysth Yes this is i want!! tq so much!! I use your first sugestion

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to get the position of a string in a list.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(group_mkt, 'AMERS TEAM', 'E-PRIMA', 'E-PRIME'), group_mkt
```

`FIELD()` returns `0` if the value isn't in the list. That will put all the rest first, and then use `group_mkt` to order them alphabetically.

Comment: I was trying like that but is not helping, cause i wanna the rest fist ordering by alphabetically too.

Comment: that should have worked.  @Wolfzat, did you maybe forget the `,group_mkt` at the end?

Comment: @ysth i try that but still not working. At least i get your answer. :)